# Couldn't connect to web proxy via Safari [iPhone/iPad] via any Proxy client on PC

Tags: proxy, ios

When I connect my iPhone to the WiFi, running a proxy using Fiddler or Charles, it works.
I set up my iPhone or iPad with proxy 8888 and of course the IP of my PC.

An error occurred stating:

> problem communicating with the web proxy server http

This was working fine last week, however it just started happening today. How can I resolve this, or pinpoint the issue?

Here is the solution that I tried so far and it's not working yet:

1. Flash the DNS in `cmd`
2. restore the firewall and reallow all the application again
3. reboot the PC and the iOS devices
4. re-configure the IP to make sure isn't duplicate.
5. reboot the router with cycling the router for 10 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was nothing just reboot my computer and all worked fine